# Angular get response after subscribe loops end

Tags: javascript, java, angular, rest, spring-boot

thanks in advance for your time.

I am looping 2 services endpoints to get data, the problem that I am facing is that I would like to wait for the first subscribe to finish in order to loop the other one, but the result outside of the first subscribe is empty and if I place the second loop within the previous subscribe, I am facing duplications and/or undefined variables.

I have tried two ways

The first solution i have tried is looping the service endpoint and then looping the other service endpoint inside the first subscribe. The problem with this solution is that i am facing duplicates and/or undefinend variables.

The second solution i tried is using forkJoin, but i have two problems with this one.

The first problem i have using forkJoin is that i am getting a Pageable from my backend (using java - spring boot) to manage the pagination, so i cannot do a proper pagination because the forkJoin retrieve the Pagination in an Array, so the details are no longer useful, since it is splitted in the array.

The second problem i have using forkJoin is that everytime i click again to fetch the data it is adding the result to the old one, making endless duplicates (even when i set my arry to empty everytime i press the button)

I will share with you guys both examples i have tried and the service endpoints i am using

Service 1:

```
getAllQuestionsEvaluation(page: number, level: number, profu: number, idComponent: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlEndpoint + 'page/' + page + '/' + level + '/' + profu + '/' + idComponent, {headers: this.headerService.addAuthHeader()}).pipe(
      catchError((e) => {
        this.headerService.serverError(e);
        if (this.headerService.isNoAuth(e)) {
          this.appDialogService.confirm();
        }
        return throwError(e);
      })
    );
  }
```

I first loop that endpoint and then i need to loop the result for the next service to get the other data:

Service 2:

```
getAllByIdQuestion(idQuestion: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlEndpoint + 'findbyidq/' + idQuestion, {headers: this.headerService.addAuthHeader()}).pipe(
      catchError((e) => {
        this.headerService.serverError(e);
        if (this.headerService.isNoAuth(e)) {
          this.appDialogService.confirm();
        }
        return throwError(e);
      })
    );
  }
```

The first code i have been trying is the following, however i and facing duplicates and problems with the result:

jsonComponentsResult is the array result of components, however that service is not looping, so i am facing no problems with it and that is why i am not sharing that code.

```
this.questions = [];
this.questionsToCompare = [];

for (let com of jsonComponentsResult) {
  this.questionService.getAllQuestionsEvaluation(0, this.evaluation.level, this.evaluation.profu, com.idComponent.idComponent).subscribe(
    (jsonQuestions) => {

      this.questionsToCompare = this.questionsToCompare.concat(jsonQuestions.content);

      for (let i = 0; i < this.questionsToCompare.length; i++) {
        this.questionsGradeService.getAllByIdQuestion(this.questionsToCompare[i].idQuestion).subscribe(
          (response) => {
            this.questionsGrades = this.questionsGrades.concat(response);

            for (let p of this.questionsGrades) {
              if (this.evaluation.idGrade.idGrade === p.idGrade.idGrade) {
                this.questions = this.questions.concat(p.idQuestion);
              }
            }

            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource < Questions > (this.questions);
          }
        );
      }



      this.pageIndex = jsonQuestions.number;
      this.pageSize = jsonQuestions.size;
      this.length = jsonQuestions.totalElements;


    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

My second solution is to use ForkJoin, however as i mentioned before, i am not able to manage my pagination and i am getting duplicates everytime i press the button even though i am setting the arrays to empty []:

```
observables: Observable < Questions > [] = [];
observablePG: Observable < QuestionsGrade > [] = [];

this.questions = [];
this.questionsToCompare = [];
this.questionsGrades = [];

for (let i = 0; i < jsonComponentResult.length; i++) {
  this.observables.push(this.questionService.getAllQuestionsEvaluation(0, this.evaluation.level, this.evaluation.profu, jsonComponentResult[i].idComponent.idComponent));
}
Observable.forkJoin(this.observables).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    for (let x of response) {
      this.questionsToCompare = this.questionsToCompare.concat(x);
    }
    this.observables = [];
    this.getQuestions(this.questionsToCompare);
  },
  (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }
);

private getQuestions(questionsArray: any) {

  for (let i = 0; i < questionsArray.length; i++) {
    this.observablePG.push(this.questionsGradeService.getAllByIdQuestion(questionsArray[i].idQuestion));

    this.questions = [];
    this.questionsToCompare = [];

  }
  Observable.forkJoin(this.observablePG).subscribe(
    (response) => {

      for (let x of response) {
        this.questionsGrades = this.questionsGrades.concat(x);
      }
      this.observablePG = [];

      for (let p of this.questionsGrades) {
        if (this.evaluation.idGrade.idGrade === p.idGrade.idGrade) {
          this.questions = this.questions.concat(p.idQuestion);
        }
      }

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource < Questions > (this.questions);

    },
    (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    }
  );
}
```

I would like to wait for the first subscribe to finish in order to loop the other one, but i haven't been able to find a solution, since it looks like looping those services at the same time are causing troubles, and with the forkJoin i am losing my pagination and i am getting all the list again everytime i press the button.

I would like to get the questions list, then, get the questionsGrades to compare if i should add that question to my questions array.

Sorry for the long post and thank you for your time.

Comment: Forgive me if i ask a query which has already been mentioned in your long question,  how are you losing pagination in `forkJoin` ?  you are already adding pages using `for` loop such as `this.questionService.getAllQuestionsEvaluation(0,....` . Can you explain it better

Comment: I lose the pagination because with the forkJoin i get an array and the pagination gets divided, so in the index 0 i got different pagination information, and in index 1 the remaining paging information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [rxjs operator decision tree](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree) page could help you with this.

And the second, I remember that I had a similar issue, the only difference was that the value from the first Observable was used as a param in a second one, and for that I used [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operator.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how would you apply your solution based on my code?